# How to get object by name in views.py django

Tags: python, django

How to get object in views.py using name not by id.

```
def StockSummaryPage(request, title):
    stocks_data = get_object_or_404(Stock, string=title)
    return render(request, 'stocks/stock_summary_page.html', {'stocks_data':stocks_data})
```

This is my views.py and in

> stocks_data = get_object_or_404(Stock, string=title)

we use pk= stock_id but i want to do it by title. So help me

Comment: Show Stock model.

Comment: here's Django docs[how to make DB queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/), more specifically you'll need to use method called `filter()` (eg. `Stock.objects.filter(string=title)`

Comment: Whats wrong with `get_object_or_404(Stock, string=title)` ?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu string=title is not working, we can write title=title

Answer (score 2):

You can get an object by any of its model fields.

Assuming you have a field called `title` in your Stock `model` and assuming you are passing the title to your view.

```
stocks_data = get_object_or_404(Stock, title=title)
```

Please be aware if you are getting an object by a field that is not unique you will get an error: `get() returned more than one Model -- it returned 54!`
In this case use `get_list_or_404(Stock, title=title)` which will return the result of .filter().
[Django Shortcut Functions: get_list_or_404()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-list-or-404)

Answer (score 1):

Here we assume that field as `title`.

**1st method**: using `filter()`

```
def StockSummaryPage(request, title):
    stocks_data = Stock.objects.filter(title=title)
    return render(request, 'stocks/stock_summary_page.html', {'stocks_data':stocks_data})
```

**2nd method**: using `get_object_or_404`

```
def StockSummaryPage(request, title):
    stocks_data = get_object_or_404(Stock, title=title)
    return render(request, 'stocks/stock_summary_page.html', {'stocks_data':stocks_data})
```

Answer (score 0):

This can solve in another way also. I just found this way

```
def StockSummaryPage(request, title):
        context = {}
        # add the dictionary during initialization
        context["data"] = Stock.objects.get(title=title)

        return render(request, "stocks/stock_summary_page.html", context)
```

then you can get data in html using

> data

keyword like

```
data.title
data.name
```

etc